# How to parse text blocks and get a value depending on another value in this block

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk

Let's consider example output of `vboxmanage list hdds`:

```
UUID:           abc
Parent UUID:    base
State:          created
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       /home/me/VirtualBox VMs/not_me/b.vmdk
Storage format: VMDK
Capacity:       100000 MBytes
Encryption:     disabled

UUID:           def
Parent UUID:    base
State:          created
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       /home/me/VirtualBox VMs/my_file/a.vmdk
Storage format: VMDK
Capacity:       100000 MBytes
Encryption:     disabled

UUID:           ghi
Parent UUID:    base
State:          created
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       /home/me/VirtualBox VMs/my_file/a.vmdk
Storage format: VMDK
Capacity:       100000 MBytes
Encryption:     disabled
```

I would like to get output like:

```
def
ghi
```

In other words I need `UUID`s of disks from `/home/me/VirtualBox VMs/my_file` and not `UUID` that belongs to `/home/me/VirtualBox VMs/not_me/b.vmdk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
vboxmanage list hdds | awk '$1=="UUID:"{uid=$2} /^Location:.*my_file/{print uid}'
```

Output is

```
def
ghi
```

Answer (score 1):

Using grep and sed:

```
vboxmanage list hdds | grep -B 4 '/home/me/VirtualBox VMs/my_file/' | 
sed -n 's/^UUID:\s*//p'
```

Comment: @GillesQuenot I know, did you even read my answer? I was only expecting him to add the vbox command to the pipeline himself.

Comment: Btw he didnt say if he is directly parsing the output or if he has it saved in a file. I left the choice for him.

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), with this, the order of lines can change, unlike other responses:

```
vboxmanage list hdds | perl -lne '
    BEGIN{ $/ = "\n\n" }
    print $1 if m/UUID:\s+(\w+)\s+.*my_file/s
'
```

## Output

```
def
ghi
```